# CSS Code only works in certain order,style tag breaks order

Tags: css

i have an issue where im using css to make a div appear circular on screen but it only works if the background image property is set first

normally that wouldnt be an issue if the image wouldnt need to be dynamicly inserted using PHP code

i created 3 jsfiddles to document my problem

https://jsfiddle.net/2wr2wajw/

```
No issue, background set first
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zvq3r0pd/

```
Issue,background doesnt get resized properly
```

link3 jsfiddle.net/x8g05uph/

```
Same issue as above, i would have expected the style code to be executed first
```

SO, whats the issue and whats the solution? thank you

**EDIT**

Found out adding the additional styles in the html code works, but thats not very nice and unnecessary to rewrite css code for everyone tag

thats what class selectors are for right?

link4 jsfiddle.net/q7sdwbfk/

```
not nice
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code is not showing up properly in each scenario is because you are using the `background` shorthand property, which in turn is overwriting previously set values.

For instance, in example 2, you are setting the `background-size` prior to setting the `background` shorthand. By setting the `background` shorthand, you are overwriting the `background-size` property.

If you don't want to load them in order so that they don't get overwritten, don't make use of the shorthand `background`. Instead, utilize `background-image`, `background-repeat`, etc. This sets each property individually and will not cause anything to be overwritten, unless the property is called explicitly again.

Here is the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zvq3r0pd/4/) for your example 2, utilizing individual properties instead of shorthand.

Comment: Excellent answer! thank you,i understand now what i did wrong. - will set as answer once the timer run out!

Comment: @TimoPomer Glad to help :)